# Detect touch on the left/right part of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitouch

I want to create a game, but I need to detect if the screen was touched on the left or the right side of the screen (in landscape). How can I do that?

Comment: Where is the problem? What did you try so far? Where did you fail? You'll need to show some effort. No one is going to create your app for you.

Comment: Yes, I know guy... Don't be so aggressive... I ask this question because I'm looking for a new method to do this. I know how to detect a simple touch anywhere on the screen, and I know how to detect a touch over a object, but not how to virtually "separate" the screen in two... I could put a transparent image on the right side for exemple, an detect when the user touch it, but I don't want to do this, I want to discover new methods ;)

Comment: get the coord of the touch, if its x value is less than 160, its on the left, if not, its on the right

Comment: If you know how to detect a touch anywhere on the screen, why don't you just check if the x coordinate is higher or smaller then the middle?

Comment: Robho drop it, until it's too late(I mean your app is appstored) :))

Comment: I simply didn't think about that possibility! Thank you guys, and sorry for this "stupid" question... I'll think twice the next time ;)

Comment: I know my app is appstored, I do this just for fun ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest looking at a good tutorial for iOS before posting questions, e.g. [iOS Stanford](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL281124C814BA2B72). However, in the mean time, something like this would to the trick:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint aPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

    if(aPoint.x < 160) { //Left
        NSLog(@"Tapping on the left side of the screen is for communists!");
    else // Right
        NSLog(@"User tapped on the right side! Ohh Yeah!");
}
```

Comment: Just one more question, what is "view in the CGPoint? Xcode says me: "Proprety 'view' not found on object of type 'HelloWorldLayer *'